# Почему моя программа вылетает после анимации на PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, ооп, анимация, pyqt, pyqt6

Я сделал не большую анимацию на *PyQt5*. И мне нужно было чтобы при окончании анимации программа открыла другое окно. Но почему-то при завершении анимации программа завершается.

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from creator import *
import sys


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowType.Window | Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setWindowTitle("PANDA")
        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.1)

        pixmap1 = QPixmap('back3.png')

        pal = self.palette()
        pal.setBrush(QPalette.ColorGroup.Normal, QPalette.ColorRole.Window, 
                QBrush(pixmap1))
        pal.setBrush(QPalette.ColorGroup.Inactive, 
            QPalette.ColorRole.Window, QBrush(pixmap1))
    
        self.setPalette(pal)
        self.setMask(pixmap1.mask())

        box = QHBoxLayout()

        lbl = QLabel("Panda ", self)
        lbl.setFixedSize(90, 30)
        font = QFont("Tahoma", 25)
        lbl.setFont(font)
        #btn.clicked.connect(QApplication.instance().quit)

        box.addWidget(lbl)

        self.setLayout(box)

        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b'windowOpacity')
        self.animation.setDuration(1000)

        self.animation.stop()
        self.animation.finished.connect(self.anim)
        self.animation.setStartValue(0)
        self.animation.setEndValue(1)
        self.animation.start()

    def anim(self):
        self.animation.stop()
        self.animation.finished.connect(self.close)
        self.animation.setStartValue(1)
        self.animation.setEndValue(0)
        self.animation.start()
        self.running()

    def running(self):
        cre_win = Creator_Widget()
        cre_win.show()


class Creator_Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Panda studio")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Азам Негматов,  что не так в моем ответе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Продлите жизнь объекту `cre_win`, сделайте его атрибутом класса:

```
...
# ----> vvvv <-------------------------------------------------- # !!!
        self.cre_win = Creator_Widget()
...
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
# ??? from creator import *


class Creator_Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Panda studio")


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(
            Qt.WindowType.Window | Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setWindowTitle("PANDA")
        self.resize(1020, 510)
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.1)

        pixmap1 = QPixmap('panda.jpg')

        pal = self.palette()
        pal.setBrush(QPalette.ColorGroup.Normal, QPalette.ColorRole.Window, 
                QBrush(pixmap1))
        pal.setBrush(QPalette.ColorGroup.Inactive, 
            QPalette.ColorRole.Window, QBrush(pixmap1))
    
        self.setPalette(pal)
        self.setMask(pixmap1.mask())

        lbl = QLabel("Panda ", alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
#        lbl.setFixedSize(90, 60)
        font = QFont("Tahoma", 45)
        lbl.setFont(font)
        lbl.setStyleSheet('color: red;')

        box = QHBoxLayout(self)
        box.addWidget(lbl)

        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b'windowOpacity')
        self.animation.setDuration(5000)
        self.animation.stop()
        self.animation.finished.connect(self.anim)
        self.animation.setStartValue(0)
        self.animation.setEndValue(1)
        self.animation.start()

    def anim(self):
        ''' ??? ?
        self.animation.stop()
        self.animation.finished.connect(self.close)
        self.animation.setStartValue(1)
        self.animation.setEndValue(0)
        self.animation.start()
        '''
        self.running()

    def running(self):
# ----> vvvv <-------------------------------------------------- # !!!
        self.cre_win = Creator_Widget()
        self.cre_win.show()
        self.close()                                             # +


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]